# Error while adding values into a table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I use the script.sql, when it arrives at "insert into" command, it generates the error number 1064:"you have an error in your sql syntax;" If I write the command "insert into" using the command line it works. Pls help me, I'm smadonnandoning a murt

This is the table in which I want to insert the values

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`impiegato` (
`cf` CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
`mail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`telefono` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cf`),
INDEX `id_sede_idx` (`id_sede` ASC),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_sede`)
REFERENCES `CarLoan`.`sede` (`id_sede`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and this is the command that doesn't work in the script but works via command line

```
 INSERT INTO impiegato VALUES('pcrdnc','abba','abba',1,'abba@an.it','abba','abba');
```

Here the complete script: http://pastebin.com/9FH7vtkj

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: "Pls help me, I'm smadonnandoning a murt" I really need to know what this means.

Comment: so where is your script fragment? ;-)

Comment: please post the way you're "using the script.sql" (the SQL code shown here is fine, the problem is in the way you're trying to use it)

Comment: I posted the complete script here: http://pastebin.com/9FH7vtkj

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in your .sql. `INSERT INTO sede VALUES(1,'CIAO','ciao,'ciao','ciao','ciao')`

Comment: @DomenicoPicerno you **have no  `impiegato` table** created in your script posted through pastebin!!

Comment: This is just a typographical error. As Morgan mentioned, you are missing a close quote on the second `ciao` of the insert into sede statement.

Comment: Nooo, if you guys fix his problem, we'll never find out what a murt is!

Comment: thx!!! smadonnandoning is used when you code for hours and nothing works as it should because of a small error and you call all the saints from the paradise

Comment: and "a murt" means "a lot"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one "'" in the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO sede VALUES(1,'CIAO','ciao,'ciao','ciao','ciao');
```

....'ciao(here),.....